# Does User Privileges affects the execution time of my mysql query

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have 2 users, A and B for a mysql DB customer.

User A is having all the privileges on a particular DB , 
and user B is having some complex specific privileges like

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT
    ->     ON customer.Table1
    ->     TO 'user B'@'server.domain'
    ->     IDENTIFIED BY 'pwrd';
```

Now if I run a query on customer DB on Table1 table, then will there be any difference in the execution times of the query when run separately each through User A and User B ?

And how does the Privileges are actually checked at the time of the query execution or they are checked at the time of connection building itself and stored some where else?

what I know is that the privileges are stored in table named as **'user (Host,User,Password)'** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions are checked for the login user at compile time of sql statement just before executing a sql statement.

The permissions are checked for only the resources e.g. table, views, stored procedure, functions used in that particular sql statement.

User's Priviledges or user level does not affect the execution time.

When a user tries to connect to the database, MySQL checks that that particular username/host/password combination has permission to connect. Once the connection has been made, before any operations are carried out, MySQL again checks to see whether the user/host combination has the right level of access to carry out that operation. The user table is the first table MySQL checks. All user/host/password combinations must be listed in this table before any access can be granted.

Comment: suppose if a user is having all the privileges then at the time of connection itself won't a value is set so that it will not check for the access again and again each time a query is executed

Comment: At time of execution, it will not check for the connection permission but it will check for access permission on object used in sql statement.